# Turn off the WCF service host in Visual studio

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Prevent Visual Studio launch WcfSvcHost.exe in Debuggin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283145/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-launch-wcfsvchost-exe-in-debuggin)

When I debug a solution with a WCF service library, VS 2008 starts the WCF Service host by default. Is there a way to turn this off so that I can use my own managed Windows service host?

Comment: Seems to be a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283145/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-launch-wcfsvchost-exe-in-debuggin

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Other question talks about debugging other projects in same solution which has a different best solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Follow these steps to disable the Test WCF Client:

1. Edit the .csproj file, and find the `ProjectTypeGuids` element.
2. Remove `{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699};`
3. Save the .csproj file and reload the project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Unchecking the "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution" checkbox is the right answer

Comment: For me this helped, because I have already done "Start WCF Service Host when debugging" and it was still coming up - and in my solution I have 3 projects - find in file helped.

Answer (score 40):

Just unchek checkbox `"Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution"` in WCF options  in project settings

Comment: In my opinion it's much more better solution. Because we still have WCF Library project type... If you want simple Library project then choose it when creating one!

Comment: Where is the Project Settings and WCF Options in VS 2010?

Comment: In the project that reference your IService Class. Right Click on your project -> Properties -> WCF Options -> Check/Uncheck "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution"